# "cannot allocate vector size n mb" in R while running Fourier Transform

Tags: r

I have a CSV file. Its size is 300MB. I want to do FFT on each column using this command:

```
 apply(df,2,function(x){fft(x[!is.na(x)])})
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 293.0 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In as.matrix.data.frame(X) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In aperm.default(X, c(s.call, s.ans)) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In aperm.default(X, c(s.call, s.ans)) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
6: In aperm.default(X, c(s.call, s.ans)) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
7: In aperm.default(X, c(s.call, s.ans)) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I am using Windows 7-32 bit  and if I run this command `memory.limit()` the result is 3000

How can I solve my problem? I can't buy more RAM ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your memory doesn't need to only fit the newly allocated vector, but also everything else that's in your R session. That's why you get that error even though your limit looks OK.

I suggest using a `for()` loop instead of `apply()`. This is maybe less elegant, but more memory-efficient, since you only have one column at a time in memory

Comment: Check the source in `apply` and you'll see it's nothing but a loop as well.